# Convert float64 to string with 2 decimal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column of data and I am trying to push to 2 decimal places from the data to get
73.35
35.72
35.51 etc.

It currently looks like this when I read the excel file into python.

```
0              NaN
1              NaN
2              NaN
3              NaN
4              NaN
           ...    
49056    73.345000  
49057    35.720833
49058    35.505000  
49059    17.075000  
49060    27.710000
Name: AMOUNT, Length: 49061, dtype: object
```

I am using

`pd.to_numeric(df['PAYMENT']).fillna(0).astype(str).mask(df['PAYMENT'].isnull())`

But only get this

```
0              NaN
1              NaN
2              NaN
3              NaN
4              NaN
           ...    
49056       73.345
49057    35.720833
49058       35.505
49059       17.075
49060        27.71
Name: AMOUNT, Length: 49061, dtype: object
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: does this work? `df['Amount'].astype(float).round(2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['PAYMENT'].round(2).astype(str)
```

round() converts the number to two decimal places, then you can do astype(str) to convert it to a string. Not sure really why you need it to be a string though

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- Do you have values >= 1000? Excel might write them as 1,234.567
- To round your values to 2 decimals use .round(2), e.g.
  `df['PAYMENT'].astype(float).fillna(0).round(2)`